# How can we modify data that is in a shelve?

Tags: python, dictionary, shelve

**I have opened a shelve using the following code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import shelve                   #Module:Shelve is imported to achieve persistence

Accounts = 0
Victor = {'Name':'Victor Hughes','Email':'victor@yahoo.com','Deposit':65000,'Accno':'SA456178','Acctype':'Savings'}
Beverly = {'Name':'Beverly Dsilva','Email':'bevd@hotmail.com','Deposit':23000,'Accno':'CA432178','Acctype':'Current'}

def open_shelf(name='shelfile.shl'):
    global Accounts
    Accounts = shelve.open(name)          #Accounts = {}
    Accounts['Beverly']= Beverly    
    Accounts['Victor']= Victor


def close_shelf():
    Accounts.close()
```

I am able to append values to the shelve but unable to modify the values.
**I have defined a function Deposit() from which I would like to modify the data present in the shelve.But it gives me the following error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./functest.py", line 16, in <module>
    Deposit()
  File "/home/pavitar/Software-Development/Python/Banking/Snippets/Depositfunc.py", line 18, in Deposit
    for key in Accounts:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Here is my Function:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os                       #This module is imported so as to use clear function in the while-loop
from DB import *                       #Imports the data from database DB.py

def Deposit():
        while True:
                os.system("clear")              #Clears the screen once the loop is re-invoked
                input = raw_input('\nEnter the A/c type: ')
                flag=0
                for key in Accounts:
                        if Accounts[key]['Acctype'].find(input) != -1:
                                amt = input('\nAmount of Deposit: ')
                                flag+=1
                                Accounts[key]['Deposit'] += amt

                if flag == 0:
                        print "NO such Account!"    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        open_shelf()
        Deposit()
        close_shelf()
```

I'm new to Python.Please help.Correct me if I'm wrong.I need someone to give a little bit of explanation as to the functioning of this code.I'm confused.

Comment: Just a word about python style, since you say you're new to it, but you usually want to use lower-case names for functions and variables. Proper case is usually reserved for classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't use a global for `Accounts`, rather pass it back and forth.  Using the global caused your error.  Like this:

```
def open_shelf(name='shelfile.shl'):
    Accounts = shelve.open(name)          #Accounts = {}
    ...
    return Accounts

def close_shelf(Accounts):
    Accounts.close()


def Deposit(Accounts):
    ...   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Accounts = open_shelf()
    Deposit(Accounts)
    close_shelf(Accounts)
```

Secondly, don't redefine built-in functions.  In `Deposit()`, you assign the result of `raw_input` to a variable named `input`:

```
input = raw_input('\nEnter the A/c type: ')
```

Four lines later, you try to use the built-in `input` function:

```
amt = input('\nAmount of Deposit: ')
```

But that won't work because `input` has been redefined!

Thirdly, when iterating over shelved items, follow the pattern of 1) grab shelved item, 2) mutate item, 3) write mutated item back to shelf.  Like so:

```
for key, acct in Accounts.iteritems():  # grab a shelved item
    if val['Acctype'].find(input) != -1:
        amt = input('\nAmount of Deposit: ')
        flag+=1
        acct['Deposit'] += amt          # mutate the item
        Accounts[key] = acct            # write item back to shelf
```

(This third bit of advice was tweaked from [hughdbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10293/hughdbrown)'s answer.)

Comment: Thank you.It served my purpose :) +1

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have more luck like this:

```
for key, val in Accounts.iteritems():
    if val['Acctype'].find(input) != -1:
        amt = input('\nAmount of Deposit: ')
        flag+=1
        val['Deposit'] += amt
        Accounts[key] = val
```

Comment: The pattern here is grab the entire shelved item, mutate it, write it back.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Depositfunc.py", line 26, in <module>
    Deposit()
  File "./Depositfunc.py", line 12, in Deposit
    for key, val in Accounts.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iteritems'              This is the error I got,when I tried the code.I may be wrong in calling it.Is rest of my code ok?I mean the dictionary created and the function call?

Comment: It sounds like you are calling `Deposit()` while `Accounts==0`. That suggests that `Deposit()` is either working on `Accounts` before it is turned into a dictionary by the `open_shelf()` call or `Deposit()` is working on some other `Accounts` object.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski: yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: @hughdbrown -- Thank you.It served my purpose. :) +1